# detailed customization of a plank

Tags: release-freya, settings, plank, themes

I am aware of plank --preferences, plank tweeks (with different themes, but I love original one) and the settings file within a .config/ directory. However I would like to change shadow intensity/opacity under a current application icon or/and change blue circle under this icon to light green and so forth. Is there a separate .css file or something else to do to accomplish more precise customization?

Answer (score 1):

`cd ~/.local/share/plank/themes or cd /usr/share/plank/themes`
List sub folders of a themes folder by `ls` command and pick a sub folder you are interesting in (for example: Pantheon, ElementaryPantheon, Moka etc.) by performing `cd FolderName`.
Open **dock.theme** file in your favorite text editor via `sudo`. Explore thoroughly all options that are available — play around, change and save it. You will see the result immediately **without** killing plank (`killall plank`).